# Perl, Sort nested hash

Tags: perl, hash, hashtable

I have a data structure which looks like this (hash of hashes):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'masterkeyB' => {
                'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
                'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
              },
          'masterkeyA' => {
                'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
                }
        };
```

I would like to sort this structure in alphabetical order :

```
$VAR1 = {
          'masterkeyA' => {
                'A' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                'B' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                'D' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
              },
          'masterkeyB' => {
                'A' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                'B' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
                'D' => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                }
        };
```

Note that all the arrays are sorted except for 'C'.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the keys in nested loops, sort the values as you encounter them. Edit: see http://p3rl.org/dsc#HASHES-OF-HASHES

```
use feature qw(postderef);
use Tie::Hash::Indexed qw();

my $unsorted = {
    'masterkeyB' => {
        'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
        'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
        'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
        'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    },
    'masterkeyA' => {
        'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
        'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
        'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
        'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
    }
};

tie my %sorted, 'Tie::Hash::Indexed';
for my $k1 (sort keys $unsorted->%*) {
    for my $k2 (sort keys $unsorted->{$k1}->%*) {
        my $v = $unsorted->{$k1}{$k2};
        $v = [sort $v->@*] unless 'C' eq $k2;
        $sorted{$k1}{$k2} = $v;
    }
}
__END__
$HASH1 = {
    masterkeyA => {
        A => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        B => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        C => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
        D => ['a', 'b', 'c']
    },
    masterkeyB => {
        A => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        B => ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        C => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
        D => ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
};
```

Comment: It *does* sort, see line `for my $k2 (sort keys …`.

Comment: The first line is not there just for fun! It protects against syntax errors! I don't appreciate it when you modify my code, run it, get an error and then pretend it's my fault. – I changed it to [feature](http://p3rl.org/feature#The-'postderef'-and-'postderef_qq'-features) to make it more clear what's going on. – You can either upgrade to a [supported version of Perl](http://p3rl.org/policy#MAINTENANCE-AND-SUPPORT) (which I think is best for everyone) or change the code to work with your unsupported version, postderef `->@*` becomes `@{ … }` around the expression, and analog with the `%` sigil

Answer (score 1):

Unlike arrays, hashes in perl don't stay in sorted order, so the common paradigm is to sort the hash keys while you're traversing the data structure. The basic code snippets you need are

```
for my $k ( sort keys %hash ) {
  for my $sk ( sort keys %{$hash->{$k}} ) {
    # do something
  }
}
```

to access hash keys in sorted order, and

```
if ( $k ne 'KEY' ) {
  # sort this array
  $hash->{$k} = sort @{$hash->{$k}}
}
```

to selectively sort arrays.

For example, say you're printing out the hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.16';

my $data = {
      'masterkeyB' => {
            'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
            'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
            'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
            'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
          },
      'masterkeyA' => {
            'B' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
            'C' => ['a', 'c', 'b'],
            'A' => ['b', 'a', 'c'],
            'D' => ['b', 'c', 'a'],
            }
    };


for my $mk ( sort keys %$data ) {
  say $mk;
  for my $letter ( sort keys %{$data->{$mk}} ) {
    say '  ' . $letter;
    if ( $letter eq 'C') {
      say '    [ ' . join(", ", @{$data->{$mk}{$letter}}) . ' ]';
    }
    else {
      say '    [ ' . join(", ", sort @{$data->{$mk}{$letter}}) . ' ]';
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
masterkeyA
  A
    [ a, b, c ]
  B
    [ a, b, c ]
  C
    [ a, c, b ]
  D
    [ a, b, c ]
masterkeyB
  A
    [ a, b, c ]
  B
    [ a, b, c ]
  C
    [ a, c, b ]
  D
    [ a, b, c ]
```

Obviously you can change the `say` lines to do whatever you are planning to do with this data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need. Not easy to ready but works.

```
my %sorted;
map {my $key = $_; map {$sorted{$key}->{$_} = ($_ eq 'C' ? $hash{$key}->{$_} : [sort @{$hash{$key}->{$_}}])} keys %{$hash{$key}}} keys %hash;
```

or sort original hash

```
map {my $key = $_; map {$hash{$key}->{$_} = ($_ eq 'C' ? $hash{$key}->{$_} : [sort @{$hash{$key}->{$_}}])} keys %{$hash{$key}}} keys %hash;
```

or shorter version

```
map {my $key = $_; map {$hash{$key}->{$_} = [sort @{$hash{$key}->{$_}}] if($_ ne 'C')} keys %{$hash{$key}}} keys %hash;
```